# Does the functor $\pi_n\colon \mathsf{Top}_* \to \mathsf{Grp}$ preserve products?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

One of the very first propositions about the fundamental group in Hatcher's book [Hat01] states that the fundamental group functor preserves finite products (it is not hard to see that the isomorphism provided in the proof is natural):

**Proposition 1.12 [Hat01].** $\pi_1(X\times Y)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(X)\times\pi_1(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are path-connected.

Is something like this true for the $n$-th homotopy functor $\pi_n$?

That this is indeed true is suggested in this answer to a different question: [when does a functor map products into products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39845/when-does-a-functor-map-products-into-products#39849), but the statement is phrased as preserving products in $\mathsf{Set}$. If this really translates into preservation in $\mathsf{Grp}$, what is a good reference for this statement? If not, what additional assumptions can I make to make true? Is it true for compact spaces, simplicial complexes?

[Hat01] Allen Hatcher. *Algebraic topology*. Cambridge University Press, 2001.

Comment: Yes, at least for path-connected spaces. This follows from the fact that a map to $X\times Y$ is the same as a map to $X$ and a map to $Y$ (by the universal property of products).

Comment: @ElliotG you shouldn't need path-connected as the OP is asking for pointed spaces, in which the only path components that matter are the ones containing the base point.

Comment: Yes. By definition $\pi_n(\prod_\mathcal{I} X)=[S^n,\prod_\mathcal{I} X]\cong \prod_\mathcal{I}[S^n,X]=\prod_\mathcal{I}\pi_nX$. The only thing to check is that the group structure is maintained, and this is true because the bijection is induced by the topological projections. Note the difference between *all* products and *finite* products. Homotopy groups preserve all products.

Comment: @Tyrone The group structure is still somehow elusive to me. In any case that leaves the second part of my question open: What is a good reference for this? By the reactions, it seems to be well known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will just elaborate on Tyrone's comment.

For a source, Hatcher gives a very brief "proof" along these lines in AT as Proposition 4.2 on page 343. The only assumption he places on the spaces is that they are path-connected. He doesn't give many details because "in spirit" the argument is the same as his proof for $\pi_1$ except for the fact that we treat arbitrary products now instead of finite, but the details are mostly unchanged. My hunch is you will find a proof with more details in Spanier's "Algebraic Topology" if you have access to it, I currently don't have a copy on hand.

---

In this discussion all spaces and functions/homotopies are assumed to be pointed.

If $X = \prod_\lambda X_\lambda$ is an arbitrary product of topological spaces, then by the universal property a continuous function $Y \to X$ is equivalent to a set of continuous functions $\{ f_\lambda\colon Y \to X_\lambda\}_\lambda$. In fact there is a continuous bijection

$$ \Phi\colon \operatorname{Map}(Y, X) \cong \prod_\lambda \operatorname{Map}(Y, X_\lambda)$$

given explicitly by $\Phi(f)=\prod_\lambda (\rho_\lambda \circ f)$, where $\rho_\lambda$ is the projection onto the $\lambda$-th factor. As per Tyrone's comment to my answer $\Phi^{-1}$ will also be continuous if $Y$ is locally-compact, but we don't need it for this argument because in any case after taking homotopy classes $\Phi$ descends to a bijection $\overline{\Phi}\colon [Y, X]\cong \prod_\lambda [Y, X_\lambda]$ (there is something to prove here, consider how a homotopy can be defined coordinate-wise).

Now, in the case that $Y= S^n$ this says that $\pi_n(X) \cong \prod_\lambda \pi_n(X_\lambda)$ as sets. But note that the bijection is given by
$$
\overline{\Phi}([f]) = \prod_\lambda[\rho_\lambda \circ f] = \prod_\lambda\pi_n(\rho_\lambda)([f]),
$$
so by functoriality it is also a homomorphism. Explicitly

$$\begin{align}\overline{\Phi}([f]+[g]) &= \prod_\lambda \pi_n(\rho_\lambda)([f] + [g])\\ 
&= \prod_\lambda \big(\pi_n(\rho_\lambda)([f]) + \pi_n(\rho_\lambda)([g]) \big) \\
&= \prod_\lambda \pi_n(\rho_\lambda)([f]) + \prod_\lambda\pi_n(\rho_\lambda)([g])\\
&= \overline{\Phi}([f]) + \overline{\Phi}([g]).
\end{align}$$

Comment: The map $\Phi$ is a continuous bijection $Map(Y,\prod X_i)\rightarrow \prod Map(Y,X_i)$. It is a homeomorphism if $Y$ is locally compact (assuming $Map(-,-)$ has the compact-open topology). To check that the homotopy relation is preserved you only need to work on the level of sets, though.

Comment: @Tyrone Thank you for the correction! I have altered my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I will have to think a bit about it to make some sense. I get the argument that there is a bijection between the sets: this is an easy observation that $\pi_n$ is just a hom-functor in a certain category. But the group structure is still somewhat elusive to me. In particular, I don't see that $\pi_n(\rho_\lambda)$ is a projection yet which is the core of the argument.

Comment: @JakubOpršal I added the details I had in mind for showing it is a homomorphism, hopefully that helps a bit

Comment: If you want to know why I get the $\pi_n(\rho_\lambda)$'s in my formula for $\overline{\Phi}$, this is part of the argument that $\Phi$ descends to a function on homotopy classes. If $f\colon Y \to X$ then I'm taking $\overline{\Phi}([f]) = \prod_\lambda[\rho_\lambda \circ f]$ as a definition and it needs to be verified that this is a bijection. But, if $Y = S^n$ then $[\rho_\lambda\circ f]$ is exactly the definition of $\pi_n(\rho_\lambda)([f])$.

Comment: The third equality in the last bit is what bothers me. I believe that it is true, but still don't have a rigorous argument. I was thinking maybe proving that $\Psi$ preserves the pre-operation $f+g$ might be easier: you'd need
$$
\prod_\lambda p_\lambda \circ (f + g) = (\prod_\lambda p_\lambda \circ f) + (\prod_\lambda p_\lambda \circ g)
$$
which you can check by comparing values.

Comment: My third equality is just using the group structure for a product, which is coordinate-wise. Namely $\prod_\lambda a_\lambda + \prod_\lambda b_\lambda = \prod_\lambda(a_\lambda + b_\lambda)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110094/discussion-between-jakub-oprsal-and-william).