# Showing that $\mathscr{F}(U\sqcup V)=\mathscr{F}(U)\times \mathscr{F}(V)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathscr{F}$ be a presheaf on $X$. If $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, then
$$\mathscr{F}(U\cup V)=\mathscr{F}(U)\times \mathscr{F}(V).$$

Does anyone have a suggestion on where I can start?

Comment: Could you maybe do something like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39845/when-does-a-functor-map-products-into-products
using this: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00XF?

Comment: For presheaves this is wrong. You need that $\mathscr F$ is a sheaf. And then the equation is exactly the sheaf property for the open covering $X = U \cup V$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Claudius correctly says, this is false for a presheaf. Indeed, simply take the presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ assigning to each open $U$ a fixed set $A$ of cardinality $2$. Then $\mathcal{F}(U\sqcup V)=A$ while $\mathcal{F}(U)\times \mathcal{F}(V)=A\times A$. For reasons of cardinality, these are not isomorphic as sets. Similar counterexamples using sheaves of rings can be constructed.

Hint: If you assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf, then you can take as an open covering of $U\sqcup V$ the set $\{U,V\}$ and note that $s\in\mathcal{F}(U\sqcup V)$ is uniquely determined by $s|_U$ and $s|_V$ using the sheaf axioms. This will allow you to define an isomorphism $\mathcal{F}(U\sqcup V)\cong \mathcal{F}(U)\times \mathcal{F}(V)$ as you should check.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the presheaf counter-example works as long as $A$ contains at least two elements. This might not be totally obvious, because of phenomena like $\mathbb N\cong \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ (non-canonically). But notice that the canonical map $A = \mathcal F(U\sqcup V) \to \mathcal F(U)\times \mathcal F(V) = A\times A$ is given by the diagonal, i.e., by $a\mapsto (a,a)$. And this is an isomorphism if and only if $A$ contains at most one element.

Comment: Thanks: I'll update this!